# SQL query which filters rows based on a duplicate value

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an MS Access query which displays the below data.

[image]

I want to write some SQL which, when executed, displays the below result.

[image]

The rule I have is as follows, and is based on **Field5**.

If the value in Field5 <> 'C' then only display 1 row for any other value.

I started playing around with subqueries and using the First operator but because all the other values in my table are unique, all the rows still get displayed.

This is my poor attempt:

```
SELECT T.Field1, T.Field2, T.Field3, T.Field4, First(T.Field5) AS FirstOfField5
FROM Table1 as T
GROUP BY T.Field1, T.Field2, T.Field3, T.Field4
ORDER BY First(T.Field5);
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that `field1` is unique on each row, you can do:

```
SELECT T.Field1, T.Field2, T.Field3, T.Field4, T.Field5
FROM Table1 as T JOIN
     (SELECT t.Field5, MIN(t.Field1) as Field1
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY t.Field5
     ) as tt
     ON tt.Field1 = t.Field1 or t.Field5 = 'C';
```

This would be much harder if you do not have a unique identifier for a row.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used your SQL subquery in my database, adapted it a little and it worked a treat.